# Will a 64 bit application support MSXML 3.0?

Tags: xml, parsing, msxml3

We are planning to convert the 32bit application to support 64 bit OS. Currently the application uses MSXML 3.0 in Javascripts. I want to know whether it will work as it is in a 64 bit os or will there be any issues.

Comment: ... This sounds like you took parts from 3 different questions and mashed them together.

Comment: I searched for this in SO but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. So that's why I have posted the question. Is MSXMl 3.0 supported in 64 bit os ?

Comment: Yes, MSXML3 is compiled for both 32bit and 64bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on a look at the COM registration on 64bit Win7 it appears that there is a 64bit MSXML3.

However use of older versions of MSXML is deprecated, better to upgrade to the latest—V6—a significant application change is a good opportunity for this.

Comment: Thanks for that. Server side code has been upgraded to v6 but the client side has been kept as 3.0 purposefully as all the clients may not have 6.0 installed in the machines.

Comment: I think it has existed from the beginning of 64-bit Windows, while MSXML6 is only built-in to Vista and later and has to be separately installed for Server 2003.